# Can a chef client use a different node_name and client_name

Tags: chef

http://docs.opscode.com/config_rb_client.html says that the node_name option also sets the client_name, but the formatting of the page makes me think that client_name might be a settable option somewhere. Can it be set differently or separately from node_name?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't.

it always (at least in current release of chef) use your node name as client name when you register a new chef client in chef server. see the [line 369 of chef client ruby code](https://github.com/opscode/chef/blob/master/lib/chef/client.rb#L369)